# What does TL;DR mean?

Tags: discussion, terminology

Very often I find **`TL;DR`** in a post. It's usually **in bold** or like a **title**.

**What does it mean?** Where should it be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"too long; didn't read"

People use it to introduce a summary section of their post, for those who can't be bothered with quite so many words.

**tl;dr**: tl;dr

Comment: I'm sorry, could you put in a tl:dr? that was just a huge wall of text, and I didn't have time to read it all.

Comment: @Dragonrage how is that?

Comment: much better, thanks. :)  though it could be bolded to stand out better.

Comment: It seems I'm a pro for getting downvotes. This is a simillar question to [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11482/what-does-op-mean?rq=1), just that one has 21 upvotes. (?!?!?!?!?)

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek I don't know. I haven't voted on either this question or the one you linked, either way.

Comment: The OP question also has two downvotes.

Comment: This is pretty much spot on. I use it as "too long, **dont** read", but then I do put it at the top.

Comment: "Too long; **don't** read" for when you're writing it as a summary for other users. "Too long, **didn't** read" is for when responding to a post. Also: [Teal Deer](http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/007/757/Tealdeer.gif). :P

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek I didn't vote on this question, but I think the reason it was downvoted was because TLDR is a general internet term - a google search would have given you the right answer. However, the other question, OP means something different on SE than it does in games themselves (original poster in SE, overpowered in gaming). Therefor its answer probably couldn't have been easily found in a google search.

Comment: @angussidney ok